# Как в отсортированной карте вывести только первые n значений? HashMap

Tags: java, сортировка, java-hashmap, hashmap

Кусок кода, отвечающий за сортировку карты не очень понятен мне, как работать с ним, как указать на индекс отсортированного элемента:

```
map.entrySet().stream() 
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размер после сортировки задается через метод `.limit(Integer count)`:

```
List<MyKeyType> lst = map.entrySet().stream()
  .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
  .sorted()
  .limit(10)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

ну и дальше получить элемент по индексу:

```
lst.get(Integer list)
```

[вот есть туториал](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html) по работе с List.

Comment: Если моя карта: Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); то чтобы получить доступ к первому из отсортированных элементов обращаюсь по map.get() и что нужно написать в круглых скобках тогда?(либо вообще ошибаюсь?)

Comment: чтобы получить первый элемент можно например сделать так `map.values().toArray()[0]` у меня в ответе в качестве примера был взят массив